# pigpio ESC (Electronic speed control) problem

Tags: python, pi-3, arduino, pwm, electronics

I'm trying to control a BLHeli ESC ([link](https://abc-rc.pl/templates/images/files/995/1424024054-emaxinstructionblheliesc-6054.pdf)) controlling a Gemfan motor (Gemfan RT-2205 2300KV - 3-4S - 425W - 1160g) with a Raspberry Pi 3B with a python program which I've written two days ago:

```
from time import sleep
import pigpio

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

pi = pigpio.pi() 

ESC_GPIO = 13
pi.set_servo_pulsewidth(ESC_GPIO, 2000) # Maximum throttle.
sleep(2)
pi.set_servo_pulsewidth(ESC_GPIO, 1000) # Minimum throttle.
sleep(2)

while 1:
     pi.set_servo_pulsewidth(ESC_GPIO, 2000)
```

Two days ago the program was working fine, the esc was starting with full throttle. But yesterday it suddenly stopped working - the esc only beeps correctly with the configuration (first max throttle and then min throttle) and then just stays silent, doesn't move. Also if i try to move it with the pigs command via bash, it doesn't work.

I also tried several tutorials & forum advice I found on the internet (such as the RPI.GPIo library), but with no effect.

The funny thing is that the ESC still works well with a simple program on Arduino Uno rev. 3 using the arduino built-in Servo library. What can be wrong?

Comment: Are the correct pulses still being sent?  If you haven't got an oscilloscope run http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_monitor_py in another window.

Comment: Thanks, but what do I compare the readings with? I mean, how do I know the readings are / aren't correct?

Comment: Run the program and you should see 50 pulses per second at whatever pulsewidth you have set.  It will print the GPIO, the level, and the time since the last pulse.  For 2000 you would expect 18000 low followed by 2000 high repeatedly.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it tomorrow and I'll post as soon as I have the results

Comment: I've a problem: running the monitor.py gives no output, no matter if I send PWM signals or receive them from arduino on gpio. The script runs with no errrors, but the only output is 'tidying up' when i press CTRL+C. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: That seems to indicate a serious problem.  If you have a spare GPIO (perhaps GPIO 4 on pin 7) run the command pigs p 4 128 (where 4 is the number of the spare GPIO) and then run monitor.py.  If monitor.py still show no output your GPIO are suspect.

Comment: Didn't help, same situation. Also, i noticed a lightning icon (undervoltage) in the top-right corner of the screen, although i power it from a 5V 2.1A Powerbank (from a wall charger the situation is the same). And the next thing is that the rpi shows the overheating icon and the Broadcom labeled black chip heats so much i cant even touch it (it heats within seconds after connecting the power supply). What can be wrong here

Comment: If the Broadcom chip gets very hot very quick after boot that indicates a fried Pi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The raspberry was fried - the Broadcom chip was hot after boot within a few seconds

Comment: Use any IO HAT. It will save your raspberry

Comment: Sorry​ to bother you, but will this proto hat (http://allegro.pl/proto-hat-do-raspberry-pi-b-2-3-i6839577177.html) protect the rpi, or do i need something else?